# How to disable all before dates in datePickerdialogfragment which date i have pass

Tags: android

**I Have on fragment which have two button like in below image.**
[image]

**Now I am to open FromDate button and set date in that which I was set on button text**

**Now I click on ToDate buttonand open DatePickerDialogfragment but with  disable all before dates which I set on fromDate button**

*How can I achieve this*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved problem. i just Use Logic for it. I pass fromdate tovalue to dialog fragment using bundle and change current date on calander with which i passed in Bundle**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myDataPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(/*the date*/);
myDataPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(/*the other date*/);
```

Comment: Dear how to achieve this.I know this method but I am using same dialog fragment in  both button click listner now on frombutton click i have disable all current date before dates .now ho on tobutton click how i can pass that date datepickerfragment  and disable all dates before that passed date